# Switch turning off automatically after leaving the view Controller using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have included a switch in my First view controller and used the following code to implement it it's action :-

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var playerNum1Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch!
  
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func numPlayers1(_ sender: Any) {
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "3to8segue", sender: self)
    
    
}
 @IBAction func toggleSwitch(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if (toggleSwitch.isOn == true) {
        
        Image.image = UIImage(named: "Image1")
        
    }
    else {
        
        Image.image = UIImage(named: "Image2")
        
    }
    
}
```

When I turn on the switch in the First view controller it works perfectly fine. But, after I go to my Second View Controller and come back again to the First view controller the switch is turned back off automatically. Any help on how can I solve this issue? Appreciate your help!

Comment: share complete code of First view controller if possible.

Comment: Please specify:  _But, after I go to my Second View Controller and come back again to the First view controller._ Are you dismissing the first viewcontroller or are you pushing the second viewcontroller on top of it? In case if you dismiss it will be dumped and recreated next time you push it. Meaning it will appear in it's initial state.

Comment: @Babar I have made an edit and provided the full code of my First View Controller

Answer (score 1):

*If your Switch toggle will depend on API response Please ask an extra key for "toggleState" bool value and then in the API response, set its state.*

**Otherwise save the "toggleState" key in UserDefault as following:-**

```
@IBAction func toggleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    
    if (toggleSwitch.isOn == true) {
        
        Image.image = UIImage(named: "Image1")
        
    }
    else {
        
        Image.image = UIImage(named: "Image2")
        
    }

   UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "toggleState") 
    
}
```

**And then Add following code in "ViewWillAppear" method of your ViewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
      self.toggleSwitch.setOn(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "toggleState"), animated: true)
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had one question, how can I Make the switch to be turned off when the app is started?

Comment: Since the switch is turned on by default when the app starts

Comment: Okay, In AppDelegate under the "didFinishWithLaunchOptions" add the following code:---

UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "toggleState")

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable above your class in that view controller, maybe create a Bool that is set to false but as the switch changes then the bool changes as well and then in the function “viewwillappear()” set the switch state to be equal to the global Bool.